# Pipeline Input step, on abort send email

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I haven't seen a way to capture an abort on the input option in the pipeline

Or a post pipeline step to send an email. I'm assuming this requires some groovy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you have a jenkinsfile or a pipeline script with an input step in it.

```
try {
    input message: "Send deployment request?"
} catch (err) {
    mail body: "Not a deployment request", to: "support@email.dot", from: "me@me.com", subject:"testando"
}
```